# Nested selects in joins: The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, nested

Here's a nasty one. I'm trying to reference a table in an outer query from an inner select nested in a join. I need to filter these inner queries on values from the outer sales_contract table, but I receive the 'multi-part identifier could not be bound' error when I try to reference any of these columns in the inner queries:

```
sc.commission_range_start
sc.commission_range_end
sc.commission_duration
sc.signup_range_start
sc.signup_range_end
```

How can I restructure this query?

```
with account_hierarchy(account_major, account_minor) as
(
    select
        gp.account_major as account_major,
        gp.account_major as account_minor
    from
        group_accounts gp with(nolock)
        left join group_accounts gc with(nolock) on gp.account_major = gc.account_minor
    where
        gc.account_major is null
    group by
        gp.account_major

    union all

    select 
        up.account_major, down.account_minor
    from 
        group_accounts as down with(nolock)
        join account_hierarchy as up on up.account_minor = down.account_major
)
select
    sa.first_name as 'AgentFirstName',
    sa.last_name as 'AgentLastName',
    sc.threshold as 'CommissionUsageThreshold',
    sc.commission_amount as 'CommissionAmount',
    sc.commission_percentage as 'CommissionPercentage',
    parent.primary_phone as 'AccountNumber',
    child.primary_phone as 'ChildAccountNumber',
    coalesce(total_credit.amount, 0) as 'CreditTotal',
    coalesce(total_billing.amount, 0) as 'BillingTotal'
from
    sales_contract sc
    inner join sales_agent sa on sc.sales_agent_id = sa.id
    inner join sales_distributor sd on sa.distributor_id = sd.id
    inner join demographic parent on sc.primary_phone = parent.primary_phone
    inner join account_hierarchy ah on parent.primary_phone = ah.account_major
    inner join demographic child on ah.account_minor = child.primary_phone
    inner join
    (
        select
            d.primary_phone
        from
            demographic d
        where
            (d.active_date >= sc.signup_range_start or sc.signup_range_start is null) and
            (d.active_date < sc.signup_range_end or sc.signup_range_end is null)
    ) commission on
        child.primary_phone = commission.primary_phone
    left outer join
    (
        select
            j.primary_phone, sum(j.billed_amount) as amount
        from
            jobs_complete j
        where
            j.time_proofed >= sc.commission_range_start
            and (j.time_proofed < dateadd(month, sc.commission_duration, sc.commission_range_start))
            and (j.time_proofed < sc.commission_range_end or sc.commission_range_end is null)
        group by
            j.primary_phone
    ) total_billing on
        commission.primary_phone = total_billing.primary_phone
    left outer join
    (
        select
            c.primary_phone, sum(c.amount) as amount
        from
            credit c
        group by
            c.primary_phone
    ) total_credit on
        commission.primary_phone = total_credit.primary_phone
where
    sd.email = @DistributorEmail
```

Comment: Wich columns are those that can't be found?

Comment: Sorry, should have included that. Edited my post to include them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to change the `JOIN`s where you are referencing the outer tables for `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY`. Try this:

```
with account_hierarchy(account_major, account_minor) as
(
    select
        gp.account_major as account_major,
        gp.account_major as account_minor
    from
        group_accounts gp with(nolock)
        left join group_accounts gc with(nolock) on gp.account_major = gc.account_minor
    where
        gc.account_major is null
    group by
        gp.account_major

    union all

    select 
        up.account_major, down.account_minor
    from 
        group_accounts as down with(nolock)
        join account_hierarchy as up on up.account_minor = down.account_major
)
select
    sa.first_name as 'AgentFirstName',
    sa.last_name as 'AgentLastName',
    sc.threshold as 'CommissionUsageThreshold',
    sc.commission_amount as 'CommissionAmount',
    sc.commission_percentage as 'CommissionPercentage',
    parent.primary_phone as 'AccountNumber',
    child.primary_phone as 'ChildAccountNumber',
    coalesce(total_credit.amount, 0) as 'CreditTotal',
    coalesce(total_billing.amount, 0) as 'BillingTotal'
from
    sales_contract sc
    inner join sales_agent sa on sc.sales_agent_id = sa.id
    inner join sales_distributor sd on sa.distributor_id = sd.id
    inner join demographic parent on sc.primary_phone = parent.primary_phone
    inner join account_hierarchy ah on parent.primary_phone = ah.account_major
    inner join demographic child on ah.account_minor = child.primary_phone
    cross apply
    (
        select
            d.primary_phone
        from
            demographic d
        where
            (d.active_date >= sc.signup_range_start or sc.signup_range_start is null) and
            (d.active_date < sc.signup_range_end or sc.signup_range_end is null) and
            d.primary_phone = child.primary_phone
    ) commission 
    outer apply
    (
        select
            j.primary_phone, sum(j.billed_amount) as amount
        from
            jobs_complete j
        where
            j.time_proofed >= sc.commission_range_start
            and (j.time_proofed < dateadd(month, sc.commission_duration, sc.commission_range_start))
            and (j.time_proofed < sc.commission_range_end or sc.commission_range_end is null)
            and j.primary_phone = child.primary_phone
        group by
            j.primary_phone
    ) total_billing
    left outer join
    (
        select
            c.primary_phone, sum(c.amount) as amount
        from
            credit c
        group by
            c.primary_phone
    ) total_credit on
        commission.primary_phone = total_credit.primary_phone
where
    sd.email = @DistributorEmail
```

Comment: This is intriguing. I've never even heard of apply before now. The syntax was a little off, but it appears to have worked. I had to move the "on" clause inside a where clause within the apply statement, but I appear to be getting the correct results. Thank you for teaching me something new!

Comment: @Donald - You are absolutely right, I forgot to remove the `ON` clause. I changed the query now, so it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

You could try moving the subqueries into views then joining on the views.

```
select ...
from
    sales_contract sc
    inner join sales_agent sa on sc.sales_agent_id = sa.id
    inner join sales_distributor sd on sa.distributor_id = sd.id
    inner join demographic parent on sc.primary_phone = parent.primary_phone
    inner join account_hierarchy ah on parent.primary_phone = ah.account_major
    inner join demographic child on ah.account_minor = child.primary_phone
    inner join vwCommission on child.primary_phone = vwCommission.primary_phone
        and ...
    left outer join vwTotal_Billing on commission.primary_phone = vwTotal_Billing.primary_phone
        and ...
    left outer join vwTotal_credit on commission.primary_phone = vwTotal_credit.primary_phone
        and ...
where ...
```

Comment: Normally, I think this would be a good solution and I would try this, but since this query is going to live inside an SRSS report, I would like for the query to be fully self contained.

Comment: That's understandable.  The same idea could be applied to the subqueries though.  Select the columns you wan to filter on as well and move the filtering out of subquery and into the join.